# Unable to read all files using "zip_read" from zip file

Tags: php, zip

I have to traverse all files in a zip file that contains 65000 files approx. But it only able to read 315 files.

Unable to find the reason, no error in error log.
I have used following code:

```
<?php
$zip = zip_open($newfile);
if ($zip) {
    $counter = 0;
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        $counter++;
        $filename = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        echo $counter . "-" . $filename . "<br/>";      
    }
    zip_close($zip);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of files in a (regular) zip file is stored in an `unsigned 16 bit integer`. This means the maximum value is 65535.

Could it be that you have more than 65535 enties in that zip file, and that this integer overflows and only shows `num_files - 65536`, 315 in your case?

Comment: @VipinSoni If you have control over the creation, make sure there are no more than 65535 files. If you have to use this file I would try several software packages to unzip and hope they read all the files and not just look at the count. Another option is to edit that value with a hex editor to 0xffff (2 x 16 bit values at the end of the zip file) to read the first 65535 files. Last option would be to read and decompress the blocks yourself with some code.

Comment: See [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/zip) for a discription of the zip format.

Comment: @VipinSoni I did some testing: looks like WinRAR (using an older version here) is able to read all the files even if the count is set to a lower number (gives an error at the end, after decompressing all the files). I did a test with a file with 22 entries and changed the number to 4. Not really sure if it will be able to read more than 65535.

Comment: For Zip files that really need more than 65535 entries, [ZIP64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#ZIP64) could be used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I found a round about (Changing PHP version). I changed from PHP 7.0.10 to PHP 5.5.38 and It worked. Now I am able to read all files.

Comment: @VipinSoni Good to hear this is solved. So you had to downgrade..?

Comment: Yes @Danny_ds, and deployment server have same PHP version too.

Comment: Sounds like a bug with later versions of PHP. Have you tried with with PHP 7.3.1? If you can and it still fails it sounds like a bug report should be filed against PHP.